# Keeping Sqlite3 Database Busy

Tags: java, c, sqlite

I am using Sqlite3 Database in my project. For testing purpose, I need to keep database busy for a long time . How to achieve that ? Is there a command or script I can write a keep database busy.

Can somebody please help ?

Comment: what is your definition of 'keeping a database busy'? Also mention why do you need to do this?

Comment: One process should keeping using the Db, while other process should wait for the db access. I tried by writing a script to insert into database for a long time through one process and tried to access db through other process simultaneously. But I couldn't succeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database is busy when there is some active transaction.

To force some transaction, just execute [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).
This could be done from your program, or simply by hand from the `sqlite3` command-line shell:

```
$ sqlite3 /some/where/mydatabase.db
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-06-04 14:06:34
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
sqlite> -- the DB is now locked ...
sqlite> COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is for *testing purposes*, one way is to have a thread do constant inserts into the database. Then you would use another thread to do the reading. I can see it being done in the following way (using pseudocode) in junit:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    //start thread for inserting
}

@After
public void destroy(){
    //stop thread for inserting
}

@Test
public void testRead(){
    //do the test for reading
}
```

The above would keep the database busy for the duration of each test. You could have a seperate application that inserts for a defined time limit. This would be done in this way:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
//mark startTime
//while currentTime - startTime < timeLimit (in milliseconds)
//insert into db
}
```

The part of the question I do not understand is:

- *Why would you want to do this?* - Are you testing transactionality or are you testing database connections?

Comment: I need to ensure that during db access across threads, the program didn't crash because of database busy